# MPAndroidChart data showing on left and right axis

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroidChart to display a line chart, but it's showing the first and last data of the dataset on the left and right axis. Is there a way to remove them from there and display inside the chart like the rest of the data?

If it's not possible at least is there a way to display the missing first and last lables in the xAxis?

Code -

```
public void new_cases() {

        LineDataSet barDataSet1 = new LineDataSet(dataValues1(), "New cases");
        barDataSet1.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        barDataSet1.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.HORIZONTAL_BEZIER);
        barDataSet1.setDrawFilled(true);
        barDataSet1.setDrawCircles(true);
        barDataSet1.setDrawCircleHole(false);
        barDataSet1.setLineWidth(2f);
        barDataSet1.setCircleColor(Color.WHITE);

        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.chart_gradient);
        barDataSet1.setFillDrawable(drawable);

        barDataSet1.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red_pie));
        LineData barData1 = new LineData();
        barData1.addDataSet(barDataSet1);

        barChart_newCases.setData(barData1);
        XAxis xAxis = barChart_newCases.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter());
        YAxis yAxis = barChart_newCases.getAxisLeft();
        yAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        barDataSet1.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());

        barChart_newCases.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(0f);
        barChart_newCases.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaxValue(1000f);
        barChart_newCases.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        barChart_newCases.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(true);
        barChart_newCases.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        barChart_newCases.setTouchEnabled(false);
        barChart_newCases.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
        barChart_newCases.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
        barChart_newCases.setScaleEnabled(false);
        barChart_newCases.setClickable(false);
        barChart_newCases.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        barChart_newCases.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        Description description = new Description();
        description.setText("");
        barChart_newCases.setDescription(description);
        barChart_newCases.invalidate();
    }

    public static class MyXAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float v, AxisBase axisBase) {
            axisBase.setLabelCount(7);
            axisBase.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            return "Nov " + Math.round(v);
        }
    }

    public static class MyValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter {

        private final DecimalFormat mFormat;

        public MyValueFormatter() {
            mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0");
        }

        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
            // write your logic here
            return mFormat.format(value);
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Entry> dataValues1() {
        ArrayList<Entry> dataV = new ArrayList<>();
        dataV.add(new Entry(10, 500,"1"));
        dataV.add(new Entry(11, 715,"2"));
        dataV.add(new Entry(12, 723,"3"));
        dataV.add(new Entry(13, 716,"4"));
        dataV.add(new Entry(14, 697,"5"));
        dataV.add(new Entry(15, 732,"6"));
        dataV.add(new Entry(16, 720,"7"));
        return dataV;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: But, the 500 value IS the first value and 720 IS the last value. They must appear on the start/end.

Comment: @gioravered then is there a way to display the labels of those values?

Comment: First, correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you are only missing one label. You have 7 values and 6 labels. 
I'm not sure it will help, but move the axisBase.setLabelCount(7); and axisBase.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); out of the getFormattedValue() method and just set it in new_cases() and try: barChart_newCases.getXAxis().setLabelCount(7, true).

Comment: @gioravered There are 2 Nov 14s but not in the code, that's why I said I'm missing first and last values. I'll try your answer.

Comment: @gioravered It worked now all the labels are showing thanks a lot

Comment: That's Great :)